# How to fix new line error when parse xml

Tags: java, jackson, fasterxml, jackson-dataformat-xml, xmlmapper

I have XML  file with data. I am use FasterXML to parse it:

```
xmlMapper.readValue
```

And when my file has a format :

```
<w>
    <t name="test"/>
</w>
```

When i parse this file all work. If i use void tag t, ex. when my file has a format:

```
<w></w>
```

All work. But if i have format:

```
<w>
</w>
```

I get an error. I want both options to work. How to fix it?

Comment: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of VALUE_STRING token  - error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am ovveride deserialize(...). Added matches("^[\r\n\t ]+$")) to it.

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/27856622/10604166.