# Jackson Deserialize Xml element with newline character as value to Java POJO

Tags: java, xml, jackson

I am trying to deserialize XML files I have no control over to Java POJOs using Jackson 2.11.2. Part of my XML may look like this:

```
<ComplexTypeA>
    <ComplexTypeB>
        </PrimitiveType>
    </ComplexTypeB>
<ComplexTypeA>
```

The XML can be successfully be deserialized to Java POJOs using Jackson with a model that looks like this:

```
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.UpperCamelCaseStrategy.class)
public class ComplexTypeA {

    private ComplexTypeB complexTypeB;

    // constructor, getter and setter ommitted
}

@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.UpperCamelCaseStrategy.class)
public class ComplexTypeB {

    private String primitiveType;

    // constructor, getter and setter ommitted
}
```

However, parsing failes if the XML has a structure like this for the optional ComplexTypeB:

```
<ComplexTypeA>
    <!-- fails -->
    <ComplexTypeB>
    </ComplexTypeB>
<ComplexTypeA>

<ComplexTypeA>
    <!-- succeeds -->
    <ComplexTypeB></ComplexTypeB>
<ComplexTypeA>
```

with the error:

```
cannot construct instance of `ComplexTypeB` (although at least one Creator exists): 
no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('
    ')
```

The error is that the parser tries to parse the newline character that separates the opening and closing tag of the ComplexTypeB element. Because I have no control over the formatting of the XML I want to treat newline characters of non-primitive types as just empty and non-existing. How can I extend Jacksons functionality to handle this case?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer after adapting the anser given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27397419/jackson-ignore-whitespace-in-empty-xmlwrapperelement-collection/27856622#27856622).

This deserializer will ignore any character trimmed with String.trim() while deserializing Xml to Java Beans.

```
public class XmlEmptyElementWithWhitespacesModule extends SimpleModule{

    private static class CustomizedBeanDeserialiser extends BeanDeserializer {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        protected CustomizedBeanDeserialiser(BeanDeserializerBase src) {
            super(src);
        }

        @Override
        public Object deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
            if (JsonToken.VALUE_STRING.equals(p.currentToken())) {
                String textValue = p.getText();
                if (textValue != null && textValue.trim().isBlank()) {
                    return null;
                }
            }

            return super.deserialize(p, ctxt);
        }
    }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void setupModule(SetupContext context) {
        super.setupModule(context);
        context.addBeanDeserializerModifier(new BeanDeserializerModifier() {
            @Override
            public JsonDeserializer<?> modifyDeserializer(DeserializationConfig config, BeanDescription beanDesc,
                    JsonDeserializer<?> deserializer) {
                if (deserializer instanceof BeanDeserializer) {
                    return new CustomizedBeanDeserialiser((BeanDeserializer) deserializer);
                }
                return super.modifyDeserializer(config, beanDesc, deserializer);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

It can be added to an existing Jackson parser this way:

XmlMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();
mapper.registerModule(new XmlEmptyElementWithWhitespacesModule());

Again, this is a really close adaption of the code linked above.